# Method Overloading in Java Returning fractional parts if double and removing them if int

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am currently learning Java via a text book and I have run into some difficulty. The text book is asking me to make a program that overloads a method, basically the user inputs two numbers and if they are an integer it adds them and then divides them by two removing the decimal places. If they are doubles it does the same thing just leaves the decimal places. I don't know how to make it show it leaves the decimal places if it is a double.  Here is my code. It all works besides the decimal places part.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

public static void average(double m, double n) {
    System.out.println((m + n) / 2);    
}

public static void average(int l, int p) {
    System.out.println((l + p) / 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = In.getDouble();
    double y = In.getDouble();
    int i =(int) x;
    int o =(int) y;

    if (x % 1 == 0)
        average(i,o);
    else
        average(x, y);
}
```

Comment: `x%1` is *always* `0` for any int.  Your program isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: You call `getInt` _then_ cast to a `double`. The decimals are already gone at this point...

Comment: x%1 gives you the remainder if you were to divide x by 1, which is 0 for any int.

Comment: the x%1 is supposed to be if it is an int then do the int version of the code and vice versa is this incorrect?

Comment: @Liste1134 The point is that `getInt` is **not** **capable** of returning a non-integer.  So if you input `3.14159` (if `In` is something that reads user input), `getInt` returns 3, `x` will be 3, and the stuff after the decimal point has been thrown away and is gone forever.  (P.S. What is `In`?  Is it really a `ByteBuffer`, or some user-defined class?)

Comment: @Liste1134 `x % 1 == 0` would be a pretty good way to tell if `x` is an integer, _if_ `x` _were a double_.  But it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your average methods seems fine. You just have to call both of them from your main method :

```
    average(i,o);
    average(x, y);
```

You don't need the condition.

If your input contains one odd number and one even number, the average in the `int` version would be an `int`, while the average in the `double` version would have a fraction.

Based on your comment, you are required to return the result of the average calculation, so make these changes:

```
public static double average(double m, double n) {
    return (m + n) / 2;    
}

public static int average(int l, int p) {
    return (l + p) / 2;
}
```

Comment: this basically works the only problem with this is It can't return the other number so if it was a double it only returns a double not the integer and double and so on

Comment: @Liste1134 I don't understand what you want to return. Your methods return nothing. They just print the output.

Comment: here is the text book question:                             Write methods called average, each having two arguments, that will
return the average of those values. If the arguments are both integers,
the value returned should be an int. If either or both values are
floating point numbers, the value returned should be a double. As
examples,
average(10,15) should return 12
average(10.0,5.0) should return 7.5

Comment: @Liste1134 Based on that, your methods are almost perfectly fine. All you are missing is returning the result instead of printing it.

Comment: how do i switch it to return instead of print? Put return average(); or something similar?